# How to tell Exchange 2016 not to use specific server?

Tags: exchange-2016

We have one production Exchange 2016 and one Ex16 which is not ready for prime time yet.

Problem is that moment you install damn thing on server all outlook clients tries to connect to that second server, despite the fact there is no mailboxes, no public folders, and server isn't ready for usage at all nor there is any reason to do so.

Can I tell Exchange to exclude unready server from serving clients?

Comment: Do you have more information about How do you Load Balance your Exchange 2016 Server? (using a specific Load Balancer or DNS name that point on the two Exchange IP)

Comment: I do not load-balance them at all. The idea was to add extra server, give it some config and then use it as reserve platform or maybe form a DAG with it. But instead somehow (well, through AD, actually) every outlook client in organization knows there is another server and they use it despite it makes no sense because there is absolutely nothing on it. And makes my job like hell, since config changes I make on that server during work hours harm clients who are connected through that server to their mailboxes on proper one.